# Generalisation of the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, linear-transformations, fourier-transform

If we define a Phase-shift operator as follows
$$
\Phi_{(a,b)}[f(x)] = e^{i b (x - a /2)} f(x-a)
$$
and recall the following property of the Fourier transform
$$
F[e^{i a (x+ b  /2)} f(x+b)] = e^{ib (\omega - a/2)}\hat{f}(\omega-a)
$$
we see that these operators satisfy the relation
$$
\Phi_{(-b,a)}  = F^{-1} \circ \Phi_{(a,b)} \circ F 
$$
or rather, that conjugation by the Fourier transform switches the action of phase multiplication and a shift.

It's not really a ''switch'' though, its a $\pi/2$ rotation in the argument space $(a,b)$. I.e., using
$$
R_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we find
$$
\Phi_{R_{\pi/2}(a,b)} = F^{-1} \circ \Phi_{(a,b)} \circ F.
$$
Is anything known about the operators $T_\theta$ which satisfy corresponding relations for different rotations
$$
\Phi_{R_\theta(a,b)} = T_\theta^{-1} \circ \Phi_{(a,b)} \circ T_\theta.
$$
Do these have a name? Or known properties? Can $T_\theta[f]$ be calculated for generic functions and generic $\theta$? Or even for special non-trivial $\theta$ other than integer multiples of $\pi/2$?

I can see that for $\theta=2\pi/n$ that $T_\theta^n = \mathrm{identity}$ and that $T_\theta$ should be a linear transformation, and I am interested in what other properties they may be known to have.

Comment: $F$ is unitary and diagonal in the hermite functions basis, so you obtain unitary operators [$F^\alpha,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform)